# Create a new folder in google picker?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-picker

I'd like to ask my users to select a destination folder in their google drive. Google picker is perfect for that, but doesn't let users create new folders.

Is there an easy way to add this functionality to picker? I'm sure it's possible to recreate a full UI using Drive API, but it's a bit overkill... unless someone has pointers on how to do that easily?

Thanks

Comment: The problem with that idea is that it takes a considerable amount of time to recurse through the entire drive and build a tree to display to the user in a scripted language.   So I normally ask for a id and assume that the either know how to create a file/folder or can read to learn how on their own.

Comment: OK thanks. Candidly I assumed that, as google drive UI allowed to visualise the current folder without recursing through the entire drive, the same technique could be used in a picker-like interface...

Comment: @CédricRoux were you able to find a way around this?
I want to allow the creation of folders on the picker UI
I haven't seen any option than to manipulate the frame